# TF 2.0 @tf.function example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In the tensorflow documentation at the [autograph](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/autograph) section we have the following code snippet

```py
@tf.function
def train(model, optimizer):
  train_ds = mnist_dataset()
  step = 0
  loss = 0.0
  accuracy = 0.0
  for x, y in train_ds:
    step += 1
    loss = train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y)
    if tf.equal(step % 10, 0):
      tf.print('Step', step, ': loss', loss, '; accuracy', compute_accuracy.result())
  return step, loss, accuracy

step, loss, accuracy = train(model, optimizer)
print('Final step', step, ': loss', loss, '; accuracy', compute_accuracy.result())
```

I have a small question concerning the `step` variable, it's an integer and not a tensor, autograph supports built-in python type such as integer. Therefore the `tf.equal(step%10,0)` could be changed to simply `step%10 == 0` right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The integer variable step remains a Python variable even when converted to its graph representation. You can see the conversion result by calling `tf.autograph.to_code(train.python_function)`.

Without reporting all the code but only the `step` variable related part, you'll see that

```
  def loop_body(loop_vars, loss_1, step_1):
    with ag__.function_scope('loop_body'):
      x, y = loop_vars
      step_1 += 1
```

Is still a python operation (otherwise it will be `step_1.assign_add(1)` if step 1 was a `tf.Tensor`).

For more information about autograph and tf.function I suggest reading the article https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/ that explains easily what happens when a function is converted.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just found a bit counter-intuitive that in the doc they didn't take advantage of this and used `tf.equal` instead of `==`

Comment: The real advantage was to declare step as a `tf.Variable` and use `step.assign_add` to increment the value - in this way there is no context switch between the graph and python  and the execution speed increases

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not visible in the generated code, the step variable will actually be autoboxed to a Tensor by the for loop which is being converted to a TF while_loop.

You can verify that by adding a print statement:

```
    loss = train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y)
    print(step)
    if tf.equal(step % 10, 0):
```